# Simple way of adding a "help" module to scripts

Tags: python

I have some simple python scripts that I use quite often, but sometimes I forget exactly how I set them up (number of arguments, order of arguments, etc). Also, they might become useful to others at some point. So, I wanted to add a simple help module. The way I did this now is by checking whether only one argument is given, and whether this argument is "help". If this is true, then a small text is printed explaining what the script does and what arguments it takes. Pseudo code given below. The reason why I do not think this is ideal is because I end up indenting the body of my script, and running everything in an `else` clause. I feel like there perhaps is a smarter way of printing the help text if "help" is given as the argument. Any ideas?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy as np
import re

if sys.argv[1:] == ['help']:
        print("""
================================HELP================================
This script generates a molden-readable file of all geometries
from an ORCA geometry optimization calculation. (Sometimes the
standard output file is not read by molden, for some reason...)

The script takes one argument: the output file
If the argument is "help", then the current messages is printed.
=================================================================""")

else:
        here comes the actual script
```

Comment: Use argparse, for this it's made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sys.exit() to simply terminate the program after the help message

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy as np
import re

if sys.argv[1:] == ['help']:
        print("""
================================HELP================================
This script generates a molden-readable file of all geometries
from an ORCA geometry optimization calculation. (Sometimes the
standard output file is not read by molden, for some reason...)

The script takes one argument: the output file
If the argument is "help", then the current messages is printed.
=================================================================""")
        sys.exit()

#No need for indenting the rest of the script
```